# Need to delete non-numeric rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I searched online for ways to delete non-numeric rows from a data frame.  The non-numerics, basically any text, could show up in columns 2, 3, or 4.  Column 1 will always have zeros, so I can't test this one.  Also, the very last column will contain text characters, so I don't want to test the entire row for text.  I tried the code below.

```
df_append['a','b','c'] = df_append.iloc[:,2:4].astype(str)
df_append[~df['a','b','c'].str.contains('0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9')]
```

It's telling me: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

I tried this as well.

```
df_append[df_append.iloc[: 2:4].isin([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])]
```

That runs but it doesn't delete any non-numeric rows.  Anyone know any tricks about how to do this kind of thing?

Some samples of rows that I want to delete contain things like this:

```
TRDG ASSETS-US TREAS SECS IN DOM OFF
TRDG ASSETS-MBS-PASS-THRU-FNMA,FHLMC
TRDG ASSETS-OTHER IN DOMESTIC OFFCS
```

Basically, if something in Column 2-4 is NOT 0-9, I want to delete the row.

Thanks.

Comment: Look up the `all` and `any` functions.  There are PANDAS versions as well, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way.

```
cols = df_append.columns[:-1]
df_append[cols] = df_append[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df_append = df_append.fillna(0)
```

That's good enough for my purpose!